# Integer number truncated when writing to text file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, integer

I wrote a download counter:

```
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('download.txt');
$hit_count++;
@file_put_contents('download.txt', $hit_count);

header('Location: file/xxx.zip');
```

As simple as that. The problem is the stats number is truncated to 4 digits thus not showing the real count:

http://www.converthub.com/batch-image-converter/download.txt

The batch image converter program gets downloaded a couple hundred times per day and the PHP counter has been in place for months. The first time I found out about this was about 2 months ago when I was very happy that it hit 8000 mark after a few weeks yet a week after that it was 500 again. And it happened again and again.

No idea why. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably suffering a race condition in the filesystem, you're attempting to open and read a file, then open the same file and write to it.  The operating system may not have fully released its original lock on the file when you close it for reading then open it for writing again straight away.  If the site is as busy as you say, then you could even have issues of multiple instances of your script trying to access the file at the same time

Failing that, do all your file operations in one go.  If you use fopen (), flock (), fread (), rewind (), fwrite () and fclose () to handle the hit counter updating you can avoid having to close the file and open it again.  If you use r+ mode, you'll be able to read the value, increment it, and write the result back in one go.

None of this can completely guarantee that you won't hit issues with concurrent accesses though.
I'd strongly recommend looking into a different approach to implementing your hit counter, such as a database driven counter.

Comment: The OP might also want to [consider flocking the file](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: Or at least lock the file with [`flock`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)...  `$f = fopen('download.txt', 'r+'); flock($f, LOCK_EX); $hit_count = fread($f, 4048); $hit_count++; fseek($f, 0); fwrite($f, $hit_count); flock($f, LOCK_UN); fclose($f);`

Answer (score 2):

Always do proper error handling, don't just suppress errors with `@`. In this case, it is probable that the `file_get_contents` has failed as the file was being written at the time. Thus, `$hit_count` is set to `FALSE`, and `$hit_count++` makes it `1`. So your counter gets randomly reset to `1` whenever the reading fails.

If you insist on writing the number to a file, do proper error checking and only write to the file if you are SURE you got the file open.

```
$hit_count = file_get_contents('download.txt');

if($hit_count !== false) {
    $hit_count++;
    file_put_contents('download.txt', $hit_count);
}

header('Location: file/xxx.zip');
```

It will still fail occasionally, but at least it will not truncate your counter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of situation where having a database record the visits (which would allow for greater data-mining as it could be trended by date, time, referrer, location, etc) would be a better solution than using a counter in a flat file.

A cause may be that you are having a collision between a read and write action on a file (happening once every 8,000 instances or so). Adding the `LOCK_EX` flag to the `file_get_contents()` [PHP Reference](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) action may prevent this, but I could not be 100% certain.

Better to look at recording the data into a database, as that is almost certain to prevent your current problem of losing count.